# RUBY ON RAILS: Why isn't typeahead autocomplete using searchkick/elasticsearch working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, searchkick

When I run the autocomplete functionality in the rails console, it works. But when I type in the search field on the browser, there is no drop down menu showing the autocomplete results. Here is my code. Any help is appreciated. I am new to this all, and teach myself by researching.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   resources :search_suggestions
   devise_for :users

   resources :posts do

   collection do
    get 'search'
    get 'autocomplete'
   end

  resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]

end

root to: 'posts#index'
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see      http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
searchkick autocomplete: [:title]
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300#"}
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


 def search
 if params[:search].present?
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
 else
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
 end
 end

 def autocomplete
  render json: Post.search(params[:search], autocomplete: true, limit:  10).map(&:title)
 end

 # GET /posts
 # GET /posts.json
 def index
   @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
 end

 # GET /posts/1
 # GET /posts/1.json
 def show
 @reviews = Review.where(post_id: @post.id).order("created_at DESC")

if @reviews.blank?
  @avg_review = 0
else
  @avg_review = @reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
end

end

# GET /posts/new
def new
@post = current_user.posts.build
end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
def edit
end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
def create
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /posts/1
# PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update(post_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
def destroy
@post.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :image)
end
end
```

posts.coffee

```
$("#search").typeahead({
name: "post",
remote: "/posts/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH"
});
```

autocomplete.haml

```
= render 'layouts/header'
```

_header.haml

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
.container-fluid
    .navbar-header
        %button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false")
            %span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar

        = link_to "Brand", root_path, class: "navbar-brand"

    .collapse.navbar-collapse#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1
        %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
            - if user_signed_in?

                %li
                    = link_to current_user.username, edit_user_registration_path

                %li
                    = link_to 'new', new_post_path 

                %li
                    = link_to '', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to log out?' }, class: "  glyphicon glyphicon-off"

            - else
                %li
                    = link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path
                %li
                    = link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path

        = form_tag search_posts_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-left", role: "search" do
            .input-group(style="max-width:181px;")
                = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "search", id: "search", name: "search", class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off"
                %span.input-group-btn 
                    %button.glyphicon.glyphicon-search.btn.btn-default(type="button") 


%script
    $('.glyphicon-search').click(function(){ $('.navbar-left').submit()});
```

Comment: I'm not big on coffeescript, but isn't your posts.coffee invalid coffeescript?

Answer (score 0):

**Your `posts.coffee` file is javascript not coffeescript.**

You can plug javascript into [this converter](http://js2.coffee/) to get this coffeescript output:

```
$('#search').typeahead
  name: 'post'
  remote: '/posts/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH'
```

**Other notes**

- the spaces and indents on coffeescript are critical for the syntax rules (which is why I don't use it). Whenever I do use coffeescript I copy it straight out of the converter to ensure I don't screw up the spacing and indents.
- your other option would be to change `posts.coffee` to `posts.js` so that you can keep your javascript
- depending on whether you use the [jquery-turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) you also need to add the `$(document).ready` check before your `typeahead` function will work

  your javascript would become:

  ```
  $(function() {
    $("#search").typeahead({
      name: "post",
      remote: "/posts/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH"
    });
  });
  ```

  or the equivalent coffeescript:

  ```
  $ ->
    $('#search').typeahead
      name: 'post'
      remote: '/posts/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH'
    return
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this code carefully and see my modifications, I left the relevant part (everything else seems okay)

posts_controller.rb

```
 def autocomplete
  render json: Post.search(params[:search], autocomplete: true, limit:  10).map(|post|{title: post.title})
 end
```

posts.js

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
    var engine = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.title);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/posts/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    var promise = engine.initialize();

    $('#search').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'post',
        displayKey: 'title',
        source: engine.ttAdapter()
    });
}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

I don't know why this weird typeahead syntax is needed but it works.
See how you should form your json response and how is the proper way to read it on the client.

you should check out this wonderful guide:
https://rubyplus.com/articles/4031-Autocomplete-using-Typeahead-and-Searchkick-in-Rails-5

hope it helps.